# extracting numpy array from Pyspark Dataframe

Tags: numpy, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I have a dataframe **gi_man_df** where group can be **n**:

```
+------------------+-----------------+--------+--------------+
|           group  |           number|rand_int|   rand_double|
+------------------+-----------------+--------+--------------+
|          'GI_MAN'|                7|       3|         124.2|
|          'GI_MAN'|                7|      10|        121.15|
|          'GI_MAN'|                7|      11|         129.0|
|          'GI_MAN'|                7|      12|         125.0|
|          'GI_MAN'|                7|      13|         125.0|
|          'GI_MAN'|                7|      21|         127.0|
|          'GI_MAN'|                7|      22|         126.0|
+------------------+-----------------+--------+--------------+
```

and I am expecting a numpy nd_array i.e, **gi_man_array**:

```
[[[124.2],[121.15],[129.0],[125.0],[125.0],[127.0],[126.0]]]
```

where rand_double values after applying pivot.

I tried the following 2 approaches:
**FIRST:** I pivot the gi_man_df as follows:

```
gi_man_pivot = gi_man_df.groupBy("number").pivot('rand_int').sum("rand_double")
```

and the output I got is:

```
Row(number=7, group=u'GI_MAN', 3=124.2, 10=121.15, 11=129.0, 12=125.0, 13=125.0, 21=127.0, 23=126.0)
```

but here the problem is to get the desired output, I can't convert it to matrix then convert again to numpy array.

**SECOND:**
I created the vector in the dataframe itself using:

```
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=["rand_double"],outputCol="rand_double_vector")

gi_man_vector = assembler.transform(gi_man_df)
gi_man_vector.show(7)
```

and I got the following output:

```
+----------------+-----------------+--------+--------------+--------------+
|           group|           number|rand_int|   rand_double| rand_dbl_Vect|
+----------------+-----------------+--------+--------------+--------------+
|          GI_MAN|                7|       3|         124.2|       [124.2]|
|          GI_MAN|                7|      10|        121.15|      [121.15]|
|          GI_MAN|                7|      11|         129.0|       [129.0]|
|          GI_MAN|                7|      12|         125.0|       [125.0]|
|          GI_MAN|                7|      13|         125.0|       [125.0]|
|          GI_MAN|                7|      21|         127.0|       [127.0]|
|          GI_MAN|                7|      22|         126.0|       [126.0]|
+----------------+-----------------+--------+--------------+--------------+
```

but problem here is I can't pivot it on **rand_dbl_Vect**.

So my question is:
1. Is any of the 2 approaches is correct way of achieving the desired output, if so then how can I proceed further to get the desired result?
2. What other way I can proceed with so the code is optimal and performance is good?

Comment: I'm not at my spark console but can you use the .toArray() method? Df.select('rand_dbl').toArray(). Neither your number or rand_int suggest that a groupby has any groups to work from to necessitate a groupby.

Comment: but the groups can be of n types like GI_MAN, LI_MAN and the corresponding values of other columns are changing accordingly, I tried to group by with pivot and it's working fine, can you please elaborate when you say "groupby has any groups to work from to necessitate a groupby", I didn't quite get that

Comment: Your number vector in the example is all 7s. There's only one group. So why need groupby?

Comment: did my answer work for you? If so, please approve it.

Comment: Groups can be of n types so i need a group by there

Answer (score 26):

This

```
import numpy as np
np.array(gi_man_df.select('rand_double').collect())
```

produces

```
array([[ 124.2 ],
       [ 121.15],
       .........])
```

Comment: I can't use collect as the current datasize is 20TB and every month, it's increased by ~5TB. So using collect won't be a viable option as it's will need a lot of memory on driver.

Comment: any other way to do the same?

Comment: @UdayShankarSingh where were you imagining holding this numpy array if not in memory on your driver? I ask because I am doing a similar thing and the only solution I can think of is to batch through the dataframe in chunks that are small enough to hold the resulting array in memory.

Comment: @seth127 I have the same problem, did you find an elegant solution? I would be happy to avoid reinventing a solution to a common problem.

Comment: did you find a solution? can the data frame be split into chunks and processed async?

Answer (score 0):

To convert the spark df to numpy array, first convert it to pandas and then apply the to_numpy() function.

```
spark_df.select(<list of columns needed>).toPandas().to_numpy()
```

Comment: This would work but introduces pandas as an intermediate step, which brings big memory overhead which is unnecessary if all we care about is getting a numpy array out in the end. @data_steve's answer is a really elegant way to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

This solution based on @data_steve's answer is more memory efficient, taking a bit longer:

```
import numpy as np
np.fromiter( gi_man_df.select('rand_double').toLocalIterator(), dtype=float )[:,None]
```

as it does not first create a local dataframe and then another numpy array but reads the values one by one to build the array. I observed the RAM consumption and that seems to be exactly what is (not) happening.

Probably you can specify a more appropriate `type`.