# Convert pyspark dataframe column of dense vector into numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, apache-spark, pyspark, classification

I am having dataframe which has a column of dense vectors i.e. Multiclass classification prediction probabilities. I want to convert that column to numpy array and facing issues of shape mismatch. There are the things I tried.

1. One answer I found on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42116143/extracting-numpy-array-from-pyspark-dataframe) did converted the values into numpy array but in original dataframe it had `4653` observations but the shape of numpy array was `(4712, 21)`. I dont understand how it increased and in another attempt with same code numpy array shape desreased the the count of original dataframe. I dont understand why?
2. I also tried `predictions.select("probability").toPandas().values.shape` but again the shape was mismatched. I used `count()` method of pyspark dataframe to check the lenght of dataframe.
3. I also tried UTF with `toArray()` method of column of pyspark dataframe which resulted in strange error like this `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 116.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.3 in stage 116.0 (TID 6254, 10.2.1.54, executor 0): net.razorvine.pickle.PickleException: expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for numpy.core.multiarray._reconstruct)`

Here is what I am doing

```
rf = RandomForestClassifier(
        featuresCol="features",
        labelCol=TARGET_COL,
        predictionCol=TARGET_COL + "_predicted",
        # impurity="entropy"
        # maxDepth=5,
        # numTrees=1000,
        # minInfoGain=0.2,
        # subsamplingRate=0.8
    )

    evaluator = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(
        predictionCol=TARGET_COL + "_predicted",
        labelCol=TARGET_COL,
        metricName="accuracy"
    )

    paramGrid = ParamGridBuilder(). \
        addGrid(rf.maxDepth, [3, 5, 7, 9, 11]). \
        addGrid(rf.numTrees, [20, 50, 100, 200, 500]). \
        addGrid(rf.minInfoGain, [0.0, 0.2, 0.5, 1.0]). \
        addGrid(rf.subsamplingRate, [0.5, 0.8, 1.0]). \
        addGrid(rf.impurity, ["entropy", "gini"]). \
        build()

    paramGrid = ParamGridBuilder(). \
        addGrid(rf.maxDepth, [3]). \
        addGrid(rf.numTrees, [2]). \
        addGrid(rf.minInfoGain, [0.0]). \
        addGrid(rf.subsamplingRate, [0.5]). \
        addGrid(rf.impurity, ["entropy"]). \
        build()

    tvs = TrainValidationSplit(estimator=rf,
                               estimatorParamMaps=paramGrid,
                               evaluator=evaluator,
                               trainRatio=0.8)

    print("~~~~~~~~~~~ Model Training Started ~~~~~~~~~~~")
    model = tvs.fit(train_df)

    best_model = model.bestModel
    print(best_model._java_obj.parent().getImpurity())
    print(best_model._java_obj.parent().getMaxDepth())
    print(best_model._java_obj.parent().getNumTrees())
    print(best_model._java_obj.parent().getMinInfoGain())
    print(best_model._java_obj.parent().getSubsamplingRate())

    prob_array = []

    predictions = model.transform(test_df)
    print(predictions.count())
    print(test_df.count())

    pprint(predictions.select("probability").head(1)[0].probability)
    pprint(predictions.select("probability").head(1)[0].probability.toArray())
    pprint(type(predictions.select("probability").head(1)[0].probability.toArray()))
    pprint(predictions.select("probability").head(1)[0].probability.toArray().shape)
    print(predictions.select("probability").count())
    print(predictions.select("probability").toPandas())
    print(predictions.select("probability").toPandas().values.shape)
```

Comment: Could you also post your code? It will help us see what's going wrong.

Comment: *where* exactly is the problem and *what* is the exact error trace??

Comment: There is no compile time error. It's all logical error the shape mismatch is the problem

Comment: can you print what 'predictions' look like?

Comment: `[Row(probability=DenseVector([0.2066, 0.1184, 0.1138, 0.1158, 0.0876, 0.0548, 0.0628, 0.0713, 0.041, 0.0306, 0.0258, 0.0271, 0.0177, 0.0081, 0.0085, 0.0044, 0.0032, 0.0015, 0.0005, 0.0005, 0.0])),
 Row(probability=DenseVector([0.1902, 0.0679, 0.1281, 0.0939, 0.0719, 0.0205, 0.0977, 0.0471, 0.0946, 0.0491, 0.0425, 0.0292, 0.0113, 0.0328, 0.0098, 0.0048, 0.0029, 0.0036, 0.0016, 0.0002, 0.0003]))]`

Comment: you are observing difference between between predictions count and test_df count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know what is wrong some people on SO without actually understanding problem reacting negatively.
Anyways since I did not get answer on anywhere on web. I had to do everything on my own and what I realised is what needs more research.

So I tried to compare the shape of numpy array with number returned by `count()` method. But actually there is difference, the number of rows returned by `collect()` as length of list matches the shape of numpy array but not with the number returned by `count()` method. So I dont understand why there is difference between the lenght of list returned by `collect()` method and number returned by `count()` method.